# Updating cells with title of each link

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, gspread

I'm trying to update each row with the title of each link in the loop, however, only one value is being populated in the worksheet. I would like something like a list:

- Women's Walking Shoes Sock Sneakers
- Smart Watch for MenWomen
- ....

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import gspread
import time
import datetime

driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)


asins = ['B07QJ839WH', 'B00GP258C2']

for asin in asins:

    r  = driver.get(f'https://www.amazon.com/dp/{asin}')

    time.sleep(20)

    try:
        title = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[@id="productTitle"]')))
        titleValue = title.get_attribute("innerText")

    except:
        titleValue = ('Title not found')

    asin = asin
    date = datetime.datetime.today()

    print(titleValue, asin, date)

gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')

sh = gc.open('Luciana-2022')

oos = sh.worksheet("OOS")

cell_list = oos.range('A2:A')
cell_values = [titleValue]

for i, val in enumerate(cell_values):  
    cell_list[i].value = val    

oos.update_cells(cell_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi your issue is located here: `for i, val in enumerate(cell_values):`

The variable `cell_values` contains only 1 value, so when you use `iterate` it only runs the loop once.

If you wish go over the complete list of cells and update their values simply do:

```
cell_list = oos.range('A2:A')

for i in len(cell_list):  
    cell_list[i].value = titleValue    

oos.update_cells(cell_list)
```